# SQL get last date of ISO_year4wkperiod

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a calender table that include *ISO_Year4WkPeriod*. For people that aren't familiar with 4WkPeriods. Every 4 weeks of the year is a period. For example:

ISO_Year4WkPeriod 2021-01 = 2021-01-04/2021-01-31

I want to create a query that gives me the last date of each ISO_Year4WkPeriod. So in this example the desired output would be 2021-01-31

Does someone know how to do this?

| Date | ISO_Year4wkPeriod |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-04 | 2021-01 |
| 2021-01-05 | 2021-01 |
| 2021-01-06 | 2021-01 |
| 2021-01-07 | 2021-01 |
| ..... | ..... |
| 2021-01-29 | 2021-01 |
| 2021-01-30 | 2021-01 |
| 2021-01-31 | 2021-01 |
| 2021-02-01 | 2021-02 |

Comment: Which dbms are you using? When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI/ISO SQL compliant. Besides, the ISO 9075 standard does only deal with a part of ISO 8601.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Presumably seeing the relevant aspects of the calendar table and sample data might help here.

Comment: I've added sample data

Comment: What's wrong with `MAX`?

Comment: Is ISO_Year4WkPeriod simply `(ISO_week - 1) / 4 + 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all the data in your table just do a `group by ISO_Year4wkPeriod` and take the `MAX(Date)`.
So your query would look something similar to this: `select MAX(Date) from <table> group by ISO_Year4wkPeriod`

Comment: you missed the `GROUP BY`

Comment: I meant `GROUP BY` but wrote the wrong thing. Thank you!